# Customize log4j for apache spark job in EMR cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, jar, log4j, emr

I have a question regarding use `log4j` and it's configuration file `log4j.properties` in Java for Spark jobs.

I have attached the `log4j.properties` together with my Spark job "jar" file, after it submits to EMR cluster my application will initial the log4j.properties file.

Here is my example code :

```
 public static void initializeLogger() {
            try {
                Properties logProperties = new Properties();
                logProperties.load(RddReadUtils.class.getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("resources/log4j.properties"));
                PropertyConfigurator.configure(logProperties);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

On my local machine it works, doesn't work in EMR cluster. Can anyone help for?
Thanks a lot

Comment: are you executing this code on executor or driver? you can also change log levl directly using sparkContext.

Comment: Can you show me some example regarding change log level directly using sparkcontext?  because my spark application running in the EMR cluster, the main() function it execute by Driver

Comment: `sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")`

Comment: Thanks, that's good suggestion. But it seems like dosnt work at EMR cluster.  In the standalone machine it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your job on the cluster, log4j will use the properties file that is configured inside the cluster. This makes sense, since your job can be more independent of the environment.

However, if you want to use a specific properties file, you can do the following:

- Place your log4j.properties file somewhere on the cluster
- Run your job with a configuration parameter, pointing to the properties file.

Assuming you run your job with spark-submit, you can execute as follows:

```
spark-submit --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///absolute/path/to/log4j.properties" job.jar
```